# Castle.Windsor Unable to Inject Dependencies from external DLL

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am using Windsor Castle as IoC tool. and uptill now I am able to inject dependencies into the targeted class easily. However what I am trying to do (and unable to do) is to inject single or multiple dependencies which are part of external DLLs loaded through reflection, but when I call the Resolve method of Container then it throws exception that:

> Can't create component 'ClassLibrary3.MainClass' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

Following is the peice of code that I am using

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullPath);
var type = assembly.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName);
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For(type));

var dependecyInterfaceAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("<SomePath>\\ClassLibrary3.dll");
var dependecyInterfaceType = dependecyInterfaceAssembly.GetType("ClassLibrary3.IDependency3");
var dependecyImplementationAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("<SomePath>\\ClassLibrary3.dll");
var dependecyImplementationType = dependecyImplementationAssembly.GetType("ClassLibrary3.Dependency3");
container.Register(Component.For(dependecyInterfaceType).ImplementedBy(dependecyImplementationType));

return (IJob) container.Resolve(type);
```

So container calls the Resolve function it is throwing exception

> Can't create component 'ClassLibrary3.MainClass' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'ClassLibrary3.MainClass' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'ClassLibrary3.IDependency3' which was not registered.

On the other hand I know for sure that all of its dependencies are referenced correctly (Path and Class names are checked).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you stepped through an checked that all your variables are set correctly? Is MainClass your `type`-var?

Comment: Yes nozzleman type var is the type of ClassLibrary3.MainClass which has a parameter in constr of type ClassLibrary3.IDependency

Comment: if its not just a typo in your comment, your class has the dependency `IDependency`  but only `IDependency3` gets registered. otherwise, try stepping through your code and inspect the content of container to see if all the required dependencies are beeing registered correctly

Comment: Thanks for all the help @nozzleman, I have solved the issue, no problem found in component registration (it was a typo in previous comment), instead a weird sort of issue was there that is I was pointing to assembly like this: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "ClassLibrary3.dll", however it should be like this: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\ClassLibrary3.dll". It looks weird because the final path after string concat have 4 backslashes instead of 2 and it was working fine, don't know how.